# Finding a multiple of some N from a binary series under certain restrictions

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

Can someone help me find a solution to the following programming problem?

I am currently using Python 2.7

Objective: I'm trying to add a series of numbers together such that their sum, when written as a binary number is a series of all 1's and is a multiple of some number, N.

Here is my generalized procedure:

(For example) 
Given bin(N)[2:]='10011'
I can guarantee a multiple, M, of N by having some m bit shift left appropriately...

such that m + m0 + 0 + 0 + m0000 = M, is a multiple of N. (Since N = 2^0+2^1+0+0+2^4).

So the problem reduces to finding m such that M is some series of 1s.

But all my attempts at coding this is coming up with junk...

I do not want to do a "guess and check method using %" or any division. Ideally, the method would self correct the m's when the answer finds a "0" in the binary string of M after adding all the m's, but I'm open to other ideas and the more efficient method, the better.

Thanks.

Comment: When you say "a series of 1s", do you mean you're searching inside the set of `2^n-1` where n is a positive integer? That is: 1, 3, 7, 15, 31, 63, 127, 255...

Comment: yes, except I don't want to use any exponentiation to find the answer, just addition. But that is the correct set.

Comment: I still don't understand the question. What are the function's inputs? Does it return true/false? Does it return an element from the agreed set?

Comment: It returns M from the set. The input is N.

Comment: "I'm trying to add a series of numbers together such that their sum...": There is only one way to add together a series of numbers! You can't say "such that their sum"... their sum is an immutable fact.

Comment: Hopefully I can be more clear: we don't know the sum, we don't know the series that adds to the sum. We are looking for both the sum and the series. We want a multiple of N which is in the set {1, 3, 7, 15...} (N is always odd).

Comment: OK. Input an odd number N, and return a value M which is both a _multiple of N_ and also _in the set 2^x-1_. Right?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Using addition and bitwise operations, not a guess and check method. This additional restriction is important when applied to large numbers. (By guess and check I mean: 1%N==0, 3%N==0, 7%N==0, etc.) That won't work well for large N.

Comment: `M = 2^EulerPhi[N] - 1` would work if you don't need the smallest possible `M`.

Comment: Exponentiation is not allowed in this. Assume Large N, so stack overflow problems are common. Addition and bitwise operations only.

Comment: Also, Euler Phi function relies on factoring, which is in NP, so this is not good for large N. Thanks for the interesting idea though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to understand a problem like this is to work out how you calculate `m` using pen-and-paper, and then mechanising the process.

- Given that the input is always odd (`n&1==1`), you know the output is odd (`m&1==1`), because that's the only way to get a `1` in the least-significant-bit column of `m*n`).
- You then iteratively perform this task:

  - Left shift the input.
  - Decide whether there should be a `1` or `0` in this column of `m`.
  - You want an odd number of `1`s in each column to keep the value of `m*n` as a string of binary 1s.
  - Output `1` if odd, `0` if even...
  - Don't forget the carry bit :-)

Here's an example, adding up bitshifted values of `n=13` (binary `1101`), ensuring the bottom row puts a `1` in every column.

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1   == 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0   == 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   == 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0   == 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0   == 1
0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0   == 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   == 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   == 0
1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   == 1
=======================
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Reading the right hand column (from least- to most-significant bits), the answer is `100111011`, which is `315`. So `13 * 315 == 4095`, which is (correctly) a string of binary 1s.

I shouldn't really be doing the assignment for you but curiousity led me to dash off a quick algorithm to prove this works.

```
def number_of_ones(stack,column):
    return sum([ (value>>column)&1 for value in stack ])

def most_significant_bit(x):
    return len(bin(x))-2

def get_multiplier(n):
    assert n&1, "Must be an odd number input"
    stack = []
    column = 0
    m = 0
    carry_bit = 0
    while len(stack)==0 or column<most_significant_bit(stack[-1]):
        column_sum = number_of_ones(stack,column) + carry_bit
        if (column_sum&1)==0:
            stack.append(n<<column)
            m += (1<<column)
        # Edited to include bug fix :-)
        carry_bit = column_sum>>1
        column += 1
    return m
```

Addendum: Depending on your requirements, you might want the output to be `m*n`.

Addendum 2: Given the question format I have taken it for granted that this algorithm will always halt, but I haven't come up with a formal proof for that. It would be interesting to see.

Comment: This is close to what I was trying to do, but I tested get_multiplier(77) and got 14622104724219, 77*14622104724219=1125902063764863, which is not a correct answer..., Also, this is just a personal project, it's not a class assignment or anything. This is really helpful and might set me up to fix whatever is causing the bug.

Comment: I think I found the error. The carry bit can sometimes be more than 1, and can effect columns further up. so it was a simple fix on carry_bit=column_sum>>1 And it works now! Thanks.